# The Big Short - shorting vs CDS

Tags: investing, shorting-securities, credit-default-swap

I am wondering, why the main protagonists of the movie "The Big Short" bought CDS, which were actually custom made for them and quite expensive.

Why they couldn't / didn't speculate on decline of value, aka to short a CDO and derived securities? Eventually, name of the movie is "The Big Short".

Edit: I am reading about CDS and I was quite wrong about them, as I considered them as an insurance, not so much as a speculative vehicle. I will still leave the question open, as I don't quite got it yet.

Comment: you could read the book, which has much more detail.

Comment: There was no mechanism in place to "short" those securities. That's why they had to invent one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to truly short something you technically need to be able to [borrow the security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_(finance)#Concept) so you can sell it.  There needs to be a system for borrowing in place to be able to do this which is very robust for large U.S. stocks but doesn't exist for CDOs mainly due to the [complex legal structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collateralized_debt_obligation#Concept.2C_structures.2C_varieties)s around them.

However, the word "short" is commonly used in finance to mean profiting from a loss of value of something.  So the use in the movie title, though a bit confusing, was fine.

Credit Default Swaps are not technically insurance as you don't need own the thing you are "insuring" (and for a [few other reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_default_swap#Differences_from_insurance)).  However, I agree with the movie that thinking of them as insurance is a pretty good way to understand them.  As you are playing a monthly premium to for a contract that pays out when something goes very wrong.

However, the movie was a little fast a loose as CDS of various types were [regularly traded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_default_swap#History) well before the bubble even started.  Though maybe not that particular type of CDS.  So while they may have been "expensive" it was the easiest route and reasonable idea.